# Modify text outside Span

Tags: javascript

Recently I am having troubles with configuring text outside span table, I am willing to just modify a specific string but everything I tried did not work properly, what I want to do here is to modify text from

> You are eligible to send gifts of up to 0 items, you have 0 items.

to

> You are eligible to...., you have 500 items

```
<span id="giftFee"></span>
You are eligible to send gifts of up to 0 items, you have 0 items.<br><br>
Gifting items will automatically transfer coins from your account to the recipient<br>
```

Link: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VgFwS/678/)

Comment: New link : http://jsfiddle.net/VgFwS/682/

Comment: And how were you attempting to modify that String? Incidentally, we don't need to see your whole page (we *certainly* don't need to see the error prompts of "*For JavaScript use the panel below or the Resources panel for external files.*" - use JS Fiddle correctly, don't leave the errors for us to correct), *just* enough to reproduce your problem; see the "*[MCVE]*" guidelines.

Comment: I want to use javascript for modifications,i just want to change that specific string into something else...

Comment: Obviously: now what have you *tried*?

Comment: I've used some codes i found on stackoverflow but they dont work when string is outside the span which causes me troubles here,i also tried using query selector but it just wont let me change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the textNode following the `<span>` element plain JavaScript – rather than jQuery – is probably easier:

```
// get the <span> element from the document using
// the getElementById() method:
let span = document.getElementById('giftFee');

// if we found an element with that id and that element
// has a nextSibling and that nextSibling hasa nodeType 
// of 3 (meaning the nextSibling is a textNode):
if (span && span.nextSibling && span.nextSibling.nodeType === 3) {

  // we access that nextSibling, and update its nodeValue
  // (the text of the textNode) to the supplied string:
  span.nextSibling.nodeValue = 'Some other arbitrary string.';
}
```

```js
let span = document.getElementById('giftFee');

if (span && span.nextSibling.nodeType === 3) {
  span.nextSibling.nodeValue = 'Some other arbitrary string.';
}
```

```html
<span id="giftFee"></span> You are eligible to send gifts of up to 0 items, you have 0 items.
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lk3jzaor/).

To make it somewhat more functional and utilitarian, here's a function that allows for some further modifications:

```
// naming the function and setting the opts as an
// Object by default (to prevent errors using
// Object.keys() within the script):
function updateAdjacent(opts = {}) {

  // using 'let' (instead of 'var') to declare
  // variables:

  // settings.wrap :  Boolean, String
  //                  false: the adjacent element
  //                  will not be wrapped,
  //                  true: the adjacent element
  //                  will be wrapped in the same
  //                  element-type as the target element
  // settings.text :  String,
  //                  The new text for the adjacent element
  // settings.target: HTMLElementNode,
  //                  the element whose next-sibling text-node
  //                  you wish to adjust.
  let settings = {
    'wrap': false,
    'text': 'new arbitrary string',
    'target': null
  };

  // Iterating over the array of keys of the opts Object returned
  // by Object.keys, using Array.prototype.forEach() along with
  // an Arrow function to update the settings to reflect the
  // user-supplied options (if no option is passed in the default
  // will be used), the only mandatory option that must be supplied
  // is settings.target:
  Object.keys(opts).forEach(key => settings[key] = opts[key]);


  // if no target is passed via the opts Object we quit here:
  if (settings.target === null) {
    return false;
  }

  // for brevity here we shorten the variable-names, and
  // declare both an 'adjacent' and 'wrapper' variable:
  let target = settings.target,
    wrap = settings.wrap,
    text = settings.text,

    // the next-sibling of the target element:
    adjacent = target.nextSibling,

    // empty variable in case we need to create a wrapper
    // element:
    wrapper;

  // if we have an adjacent element and that adjacent element
  // is of nodeType 3 (a textNode):
  if (adjacent && adjacent.nodeType === 3) {

    // if wrap is not-equal to (Boolean) false:
    if (wrap !== false) {

      // if wrap is Boolean true (no element-type was specified):
      if (wrap === true) {

        // we create a new element of the same type as the
        // target:
        wrapper = document.createElement(target.localName);

      // otherwise if the wrap variable is a String:
      } else if ('string' === typeof wrap) {

        // we create an element of that specified type:
        wrapper = document.createElement(wrap);
      }

      // retrieving the parentNode of the target, and using
      // Node.insertBefore() to append the new-child (wrapper)
      // before the existing adjacent node:
      target.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, adjacent);

      // moving the adjacent node into the wrapper:
      wrapper.appendChild(adjacent);
    }
  }

  // here we update the nodevalue of the adjacent node
  // which is still referenced by the 'adjacent' variable
  // whether it remains 'physically' adjacent or newly-wrapped:
  adjacent.nodeValue = text;

  // here we return the adjacent node (if it was never wrapped),
  // or the newly-created parentNode (if the adjacent node was
  // wrapped):
  return wrap === false ? adjacent : adjacent.parentNode;
}

updateAdjacent({
  'target': document.getElementById('giftFee'),
  'text': 'Whatever text you might care to add.'
});
```

```js
function updateAdjacent(opts = {}) {
  let settings = {
    'wrap': false,
    'text': 'new arbitrary string',
    'target': null
  };

  Object.keys(opts).forEach(key => settings[key] = opts[key]);

  if (settings.target === null) {
    return false;
  }

  let target = settings.target,
    adjacent = target.nextSibling,
    wrap = settings.wrap,
    text = settings.text,
    wrapper;

  if (adjacent && adjacent.nodeType === 3) {
    if (wrap !== false) {
      if (wrap === true) {
        wrapper = document.createElement(target.localName);
      } else if ('string' === typeof wrap) {
        wrapper = document.createElement(wrap);
      }
      target.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, adjacent);
      wrapper.appendChild(adjacent);
    }
  }

  adjacent.nodeValue = text;

  return wrap === false ? adjacent : adjacent.parentNode;
}

updateAdjacent({
  'target': document.getElementById('giftFee'),
  'text': 'Whatever text you might care to add.'
});
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em 0.5em 0 0;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
span[id]::before {
  content: '(id: ' attr(id) ') ';
}
#newSibling {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<span id="giftFee"></span> You are eligible to send gifts of up to 0 items, you have 0 items.
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lk3jzaor/1/).

The above can be be called in multiple ways, of course, and also chained if required. For example if we wrap the adjacent element (by passing `true`) we can then set the `id` of that new parent to apply a style found in the stylesheet:

```js
function updateAdjacent(opts = {}) {
  let settings = {
    'wrap': false,
    'text': 'new arbitrary string',
    'target': null
  };

  Object.keys(opts).forEach(key => settings[key] = opts[key]);

  if (settings.target === null) {
    return false;
  }

  let target = settings.target,
    adjacent = target.nextSibling,
    wrap = settings.wrap,
    text = settings.text,
    wrapper;

  if (adjacent && adjacent.nodeType === 3) {
    if (wrap !== false) {
      if (wrap === true) {
        wrapper = document.createElement(target.localName);
      } else if ('string' === typeof wrap) {
        wrapper = document.createElement(wrap);
      }
      target.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, adjacent);
      wrapper.appendChild(adjacent);
    }
  }

  adjacent.nodeValue = text;

  return wrap === false ? adjacent : adjacent.parentNode;
}

updateAdjacent({
  'target': document.getElementById('giftFee'),
  'wrap': true
}).id = 'newSibling';
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em 0.5em 0 0;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
span[id]::before {
  content: '(id: ' attr(id)') ';
}
#newSibling {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<span id="giftFee"></span> You are eligible to send gifts of up to 0 items, you have 0 items.
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lk3jzaor/2/).

Or we can wrap in a `<b>` element, by passing `'b'` as the `opts.wrap` option-value, and directly update its `style` property to add a `text-decoration`:

updateAdjacent({
  'target': document.getElementById('giftFee'),
  'wrap': 'b',
  'text': 'Whatever text you might care to add.'
}).style.textDecoration = 'overline';

```js
function updateAdjacent(opts = {}) {
  let settings = {
    'wrap': false,
    'text': 'new arbitrary string',
    'target': null
  };

  Object.keys(opts).forEach(key => settings[key] = opts[key]);

  if (settings.target === null) {
    return false;
  }

  let target = settings.target,
    adjacent = target.nextSibling,
    wrap = settings.wrap,
    text = settings.text,
    wrapper;

  if (adjacent && adjacent.nodeType === 3) {
    if (wrap !== false) {
      if (wrap === true) {
        wrapper = document.createElement(target.localName);
      } else if ('string' === typeof wrap) {
        wrapper = document.createElement(wrap);
      }
      target.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, adjacent);
      wrapper.appendChild(adjacent);
    }
  }

  adjacent.nodeValue = text;

  return wrap === false ? adjacent : adjacent.parentNode;
}

updateAdjacent({
  'target': document.getElementById('giftFee'),
  'wrap': 'b',
  'text': 'Whatever text you might care to add.'
}).style.textDecoration = 'overline';
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em 0.5em 0 0;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
span[id]::before {
  content: '(id: ' attr(id)') ';
}
```

```html
<span id="giftFee"></span> You are eligible to send gifts of up to 0 items, you have 0 items.
```

Or directly add an event-listener:

```
updateAdjacent({
  'target': document.getElementById('giftFee'),
  'wrap': 'b',
  'text': 'Whatever text you might care to add.'
}).addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let target = e.target,
      opacity = window.getComputedStyle(target,null).opacity;

      target.style.opacity = opacity === '1' ? '0.5' : '1';
});
```

```js
function updateAdjacent(opts = {}) {
  let settings = {
    'wrap': false,
    'text': 'new arbitrary string',
    'target': null
  };

  Object.keys(opts).forEach(key => settings[key] = opts[key]);

  if (settings.target === null) {
    return false;
  }

  let target = settings.target,
    adjacent = target.nextSibling,
    wrap = settings.wrap,
    text = settings.text,
    wrapper;

  if (adjacent && adjacent.nodeType === 3) {
    if (wrap !== false) {
      if (wrap === true) {
        wrapper = document.createElement(target.localName);
      } else if ('string' === typeof wrap) {
        wrapper = document.createElement(wrap);
      }
      target.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, adjacent);
      wrapper.appendChild(adjacent);
    }
  }

  adjacent.nodeValue = text;

  return wrap === false ? adjacent : adjacent.parentNode;
}

updateAdjacent({
  'target': document.getElementById('giftFee'),
  'wrap': 'b',
  'text': 'Whatever text you might care to add.'
}).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let target = e.target,
    opacity = window.getComputedStyle(target, null).opacity;

  target.style.opacity = opacity === '1' ? '0.5' : '1';
});
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em 0.5em 0 0;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
span[id]::before {
  content: '(id: ' attr(id)') ';
}
```

```html
<span id="giftFee"></span> You are eligible to send gifts of up to 0 items, you have 0 items.
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Conditional (ternary) operator: `statement ? ifTrue : ifFalse;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
- [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).
- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: Hello ,thanks for the answer but i just tried this script on my Greasemonkey and it doesnt work on my page,no changes actually happen but on fiddle i can see them..got any hint what is wrong?

Comment: I also tried alerting the value but i get nothing out..Pretty weird
alert(span.nextSibling.nodeValue);

Comment: And are there any errors? "*It doesn't work...no changes actually happen*" isn't an error description I can respond to, unfortunately. What's different in your page? Does the script run before, or after, the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Basically what i think is the problem is the fact that those elements (string i want to modify) spawns only after i click some button,and i guess the script does not recognize it when i reload page as it does not exist,only when i click the button those text spawns..Is there any way we could fix this,maybe activate script on action?

Comment: update : i fixed it with a script that reloads a given script in 50ms interval : )

Comment: To trigger the function in response to an event simply use `EventTarget.addEventListener('eventName', function () { updateAdjacent(opts); });` (note that there is a link to the MDN reference for `EventTarget.addEventListener()` in the references at the bottom of the answer).